# Using File.Exists() to check if views exist on disk

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'd like to build a way to override for ASP.NET MVC views at runtime. Basic idea is to have *MyView.cshtml* and and optional *MyView.Override.cshtml*. As soon as *MyView.Override.cshtml* is present on the disk, it shall be used instead of the original view.

What I'm trying to do is:

```
protected new ActionResult View(string viewName)
{
    var overridePath = viewName.Replace(".cshtml", ".Override.cshtml"); // i.e. ~/Views/MyView.Override.cshtml

    if (System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath(overridePath)))
    {
        return base.View(overridePath); // use override
    }

    return base.View(viewName); // use default
}
```

This basically works. My question: Is it good practice to do use *File.Exists()* when resolving views? Will this introduce any issues (Flexibility, Performance)? Am I missing a standard MVC way to do the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this possibility for EVERY page in your application, then there is already a way to do this called [DisplayModeProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.virtualpathproviderviewengine.displaymodeprovider%28v=vs.118%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). The typical use-case for this is for having mobile or browser-specific Views.

For example, you can set up an Index.Mobile.cshtml, and the built-in provider will return that view instead of Index.cshtml if it determines that the requesting browser is a mobile device based on the User Agent string.

However, you can [create your own](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b696c4/display-mode-provider-in-mvc-5-application/) provider to add additional ones that will return for whatever reason you wish.

Inside your Startup or Global.asax (depending on OWIN, etc), you will want to add the following code:

```
DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(1, new DefaultDisplayMode("Override")  
{  
    // Make it always try this
    ContextCondition = (ctx => true)     
});
```

With this in your code, it will always try to return a xxxx.Override.cshtml view. If that doesn't exist, it will fall back to the regular view.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thanks.
Also, display mode provider seems to have a smarter approach to checking if files exist by doing it at application startup instead of every single time a view is resolved.